# sql inner join single table

Tags: sql

Three column table; ID, TERM, SYNONYM

```
1, IDENTITY, CHARACTER
2, IDENTITY, EXISTENCE
3, IDENTITY, IDENTIFICATION
4, IDENTITY, INTEGRITY 
5, IDENTITY, NAME
6, CIRCUMSTANCES, ASSETS
7, CIRCUMSTANCES, CAPITAL
8, CIRCUMSTANCES, CHANCES
```

I need the result to return distinct "term" with associated "synonym(s)" eliminating many to many and bring back one to many as the result.

```
1, IDENTITY, CHARACTER | EXISTENCE | IDENTIFICATION | INTEGRITY | NAME
6, CIRCUMSTANCES, ASSETS |CAPITAL | CHANCES
```

Or,

1, TERM="IDENTITY" SYNONYM="CHARACTER" SYNONYM="EXISTENCE" SYNONYM="IDENTIFICATION" SYNONYM="INTEGRITY" SYNONYM="NAME"

2, TERM="CIRCUMSTANCES" SYNONYM="ASSETS" SYNONYM="CAPITAL" SYNONYM="CHANCES"

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT MIN(`ID`), `TERM`, GROUP_CONCAT(`SYNONYM`, ' | ') 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY `TERM`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.GROUP_CONCAT not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Oracle solution - since 11g:

```
with sample as
(
  select 1 ID,  'IDENTITY' term , 'CHARACTER' syn from dual
  union all
  select 2, 'IDENTITY', 'EXISTENCE' from dual 
  union all
  select 3, 'IDENTITY', 'IDENTIFICATION' from dual 
  union all
  select 4, 'IDENTITY', 'INTEGRITY' from dual 
  union all
  select 5, 'IDENTITY', 'NAME' from dual 
  union all
  select 6, 'CIRCUMSTANCES', 'ASSETS' from dual 
  union all
  select 7, 'CIRCUMSTANCES', 'CAPITAL' from dual 
  union all
  select 8, 'CIRCUMSTANCES', 'CHANCES' from dual 
)
select  min(id) id, term,
listagg(syn,'|') within group(order by syn) syns
from sample
group by term;
```

Output:

```
      ID TERM          SYNS
---------- ------------- ------------------------------------------------------
         6 CIRCUMSTANCES ASSETS|CAPITAL|CHANCES
         1 IDENTITY      CHARACTER|EXISTENCE|IDENTIFICATION|INTEGRITY|NAME
```

Comment: It's against DB2 and doesn't like the WITHIN but I have a good picture now and will work through it.  Thanks!